# Escrever dentro de uma div com uma função

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma função que pega valores de um documento via parser:

```
    var soma = 0;

    $(document).ready(function () {

    $.get(file, function (data) {
        ivps = parseDataToIvp(data);        
        let fIvps = ivps.filter(i => i.idleTime < -60)                
        fIvps.map(i => console.log(i.idleTime))
        soma = fIvps.map(i => i.idleTime).reduce((a,b) => a + b);

        console.log(soma);
    });

});
```

Gostaria de escrever esse resultado "soma" dentro da minha div no HTML, porém não estou conseguindo, alguém tem alguma idéia?

```
<div class="count"></div>
```

Comment: Felipe Deolindo, faz um teste usando o código que adicionei como resposta e me diga se era o que você queria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para se adequar ao seu código, você pode usar o comando `.innerHTML` para inserir o valor da sua variável `soma` dando um `document.getElementsByClassName` para capturar o elemento desejado.

Adapte o seu código com o seguinte código:

```
var soma = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $.get(file, function (data) {
        ivps = parseDataToIvp(data);        
        let fIvps = ivps.filter(i => i.idleTime < -60)                
        fIvps.map(i => console.log(i.idleTime))
        soma = fIvps.map(i => i.idleTime).reduce((a,b) => a + b);

        console.log(soma); //Caso você queira apenas inserir o valor na sua <div>, remover essa linha.
        document.getElementsByClassName("count")[0].innerHTML = soma;

    });


});
```

Comment: André fiz isso, porém esse valor que estou pegando de uma planilha do excel é dinamico, ele todo dia soma todos os valores e me gerá um resultado, com esse seu código o valor que me mostra é sempre 0, porque é o valor que está declarado lá em cima

Comment: A variável está declarada lá em cima por **0**, mas o `innerHTML` está adicionando o valor retornado dessa sua função:`fIvps.map(i => i.idleTime).reduce((a,b) => a + b);` que provavelmente está retornando 0.

Comment: @FelipeDeolindo, qual valor o seu `console.log` exibe?

Comment: o valor que meu console está mostrando, o valor total somando todos eles é `-1674` , ele me mostra todos os valores que estão sendo pegos e no final mostra o total deles, mas amanhã esse valor será outro, assim por diante, todo dia esse valor final muda

Comment: Deu certo cara, faltava um ; no final, não me atentei, muito obrigado

Comment: não querendo abusar, mas eu li que se usar aquele `math.abs` eu consigo fazer esse número negativo virar positivo, sabe onde posso usar o `math.abs` dentro dessa função?

Comment: Caso a variável `soma` retorne um valor negativo, por exemplo: **-15**. você deseja retornar **15** ? Se for isso que deseja, basta subtituir o código: `= soma;` por `= abs(soma);`. Vale lembrar que a *função* `abs` só aceita como prâmetro valores numéricos.

Answer (score 1):

Para inserir queira inserir dentro da div algum conteúdo, você pode fazer das seguintes formas:

**Conteúdo em HTML:**

- `$('div.count').html('Seu código HTML aqui');`
- `document.querySelector('div.count').innerHTML = 'Seu código HTML aqui';`

**Conteúdo em texto simples:**

- `$('div.count').text('Seu texto aqui');`
- `document.querySelector('div.count').innerText = 'Seu texto aqui';`

Acima mostro como você pode fazer essa inserção, tanto com JQuery, como apenas com Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
var soma = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {

$.get(file, function (data) {
    ivps = parseDataToIvp(data);        
    let fIvps = ivps.filter(i => i.idleTime < -60)                
    fIvps.map(i => console.log(i.idleTime))
    soma = fIvps.map(i => i.idleTime).reduce((a,b) => a + b);

    console.log(soma);
});

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = soma;

});

  <div class="count" id="result"></div>
```

ou

```
  <div>
        <p id="result">Calculando valores....</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tentou isso?

```
$("#div_id").html("seu texto aqui");
```

Obs.: código usando jQuery

Comment: @AndréFilipe nesse caso você substituiria esse ID pelo ID da sua div.
Recomendo usar o atributo "id" para seleção, pois se trata de um identificador único.
Use classe quando quiser selecionar um conjunto de elementos na tela.